# Is there a maximum Time Stamp Validity Duration when a client is set to a future datetime vs the server

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

We set our Security on our custom Binding as below:

```
var lSecurity = lCustomBinding.Elements.Find<TransportSecurityBindingElement>();
                lSecurity.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
                lSecurity.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
                lSecurity.LocalClientSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                lSecurity.LocalServiceSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                lSecurity.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                lSecurity.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
```

Now we find that if we test the above by setting the client back anywhere from now to 7 days back, it works. However, the moment we set the client anything more than 9 hours into the future, we get an exception.

The only thing we found was some obscure reference at the end of another thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/7c3a7a7e-b9a5-4198-9a29-c6d4e408d36d

Does anybody have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
The Exception we get is now added below. It seems as though the server rejects the client message:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException occurred
  Message=An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.RenewTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout, SecurityToken tokenToBeRenewed)
       at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.RenewToken(TimeSpan timeout, SecurityToken tokenToBeRenewed)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.RenewKey(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.SecureOutgoingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecurityDuplexSessionChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.DuplexClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnSend(TDuplexChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SendReceiveReliableRequestor.OnRequest(Message request, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean last)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.Request(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableSession.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at CompuLoan.Maintenance.IMaintenanceService.IsLicensed(String pHardwareId, Boolean pUseLicense)
       at CompuLoan.Maintenance.MaintenanceServiceClient.IsLicensed(String pHardwareId, Boolean pUseLicense) in C:\Development\compuloan\Source\CompuLoan\Service References\Maintenance\Reference.cs:line 5156
       at CompuLoan.App.IsLicensed(Boolean pUseLicense) in C:\Development\compuloan\Source\CompuLoan\App.xaml.cs:line 365
  InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException
       Message=The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Sorry, Jano, I really have nothing to contribute but your question and link reminded me of this: http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: On second thought, perhaps the 9 hours is somehow associated with your time zone's relation to UTC, or possibly the international date line?

Comment: maybe the client throws the exception when it gets the server response and not the other way around? check using wcf lossing. also please publish the full exception and its stack trace.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - we came to the same conclusion, that based on our GMT+2(South Africa) the limit before moving into "the next day" would be nine hours. I would then assume that this value increase / decreases relative to GMT, or in fact, UTC. My question would then be, if this is the case, why is there no mention on MSDN when going through the Security Documentation? ;-) Having someone test / verify this would be awesome. Will try and post the exception. ps. I loved that xkcd...

Comment: @YaronNaveh - Exception added.

Answer (score 1):

This is expiration of the session key, which is different than timestamp. For example of you turn establishSecurityContext off (or not use CreateSecureConversationSecurity) you should not get this exception.

Otherwise try to increase additional values such as InactivityTimeout, IssuedCookieLifetime, NegotiationTimeout, SessionKeyRenewalInterval and SessionKeyRolloverInterval.

If you turn on WCF trace on the server and see the exact stack trace of the error maybe we can dril down to the exact property.